# Leaflet + MarkerCluster + custom Icons + Popups

Tags: popup, icons, leaflet, markerclusterer

I'd like to use custom icons for my markers, while using Leaflet [MarkerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

I already **managed to implement my custom icons**, but **now the marker popups** aren't working any more.

My code looks like this:

```js
var markers1 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

// add markers with popup info
var geoJsonLayer1 = L.geoJson(Myplaces, {
   onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name);
   }
})

// add markers with custom icons
var geoJsonLayer1 = L.geoJson(Myplaces, {
   onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
   pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      var iconURL = feature.properties.img;
      return new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(feature.geometry.coordinates[1], feature.geometry.coordinates[0]), {
         icon: L.icon({
            iconAnchor: [0, 0],
            popupAnchor: [0, 0],
            iconUrl: iconURL
         })
      });
   }
})

// add markers to map
markers1.addLayer(geoJsonLayer1);
map.addLayer(markers1);
```

When I remove the part for the custom icons (the section below "// add markers with custom icons"),
the marker popups work just fine again…

Any suggestions? 
***Thanks so much in advance for any help!!***

(I tried everything I could think of & I'm going crazy here…) ; )

Comment: ps: should/can I combine the 2 "onEachFeature"-actions? Is it not working because I'm using the var name "geoJsonLayer1" twice?

Comment: …or is there an entirely different (and smarter) way to implement custom icons with MarkerCluster?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Oops! misunderstood your question. Yeah the issue is you are doing L.geoJson twice and doing different things with them. This function returns a new L.GeoJson object, so the things you add your popups to are not the things you are making custom markers. So yeah you should just combine them.

```
var geoJson = L.geoJson(geoJsonData, {
    pointToLayer: function(obj) {
        var mark = L.circleMarker(obj.geometry.coordinates, obj.properties);
        mark.bindPopup('<div>' + marks.length + '</div>');
        return mark;
    }
});
```

This piece of code is from and updated example I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3tnjL/2/).

I'll leave in the bit below about custom cluster icons.

As a side note, it's typically bad practice to attempt to create two vars with the same name, and most linters will complain about that.

...

I created a little demo that uses clustering, popups and custom icons [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3tnjL/).

When you create the MarkerClusterGroup you can give it an arbitrary function with creates the icons for clusters:

```
iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
    var count = cluster.getChildCount();
    return L.divIcon({
        html: '<span class="custom">' + (count + 100) + '</span>'
    })
}
```

Where you can put your logic for custom cluster icons. For single markers, you can pass an icon the the constructor directly. You'll also notice that popups work for markers and clusters.

EDIT: The previous jsfiddles now have incompatibility with leaflet and markercluster versions. Here is a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/3tnjL/59/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks so much for your answer and all your work! I couldn't see any markers in your demo - but I tried to implement the code into my example.. so far no markers show up, but I guess I'm overseeing just a small detail?

2 quick questions:
1) the center of my map has the following coordinates:
center: new L.LatLng(52.520287, 13.405886),
…and all my markers are in the surrounding area. Should I edit your line, and in which way?

Comment: 2) I replaced the var name "whatever" (var data = "whatever";) with my var name "Myplaces" from a js file, which has the following structure:

var Myplaces = {"name":"Myplaces","type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "lala", "Description": "", "img": "my-icon2.png" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 13.39545, 52.528111, 0.0 ] } },
…

Should it be working like that, or do I have to make additional changes to your code? Thanks again, Julia

Comment: Yeah I was just placing markers randomly in the world, so you'd have to zoom all the way out. Also sorry I misunderstood the question, and I've updated the answer I posted.

Comment: thanks a lot again! silly me, i should have zoomed out a bit more in your first example…! Well, I replicated your second example - and I'm embarrassed, but it seems I'm too stupid to find any markers in it… (this time i zoomed all the way out/in, but still…)

Comment: @hassassin your fiddles have error ```Uncaught TypeError: this._featureGroup.addEventParent is not a function```

Comment: Thanks @Luckylooke There was an issue that markerclusterer updated the cdn for the source, but leaflet did not, so there was an incompatibility. I updated the versions in the fiddle and linked a working example at the bottom.